# Populate a local Datastore based on appspot Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I have populated a datastore and have webapp2 serving up some graphs to display the data when I go to my deployed appspot site. However, for development purposes I would like to be able to run an instance of Google App Engine locally against the same data.  I have read the Google Docs about backup and restore (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin?csw=1#backup_and_restore) but that doesn't seem to provide any options for populating seed data to the local instance.

Does anyone know how to either export data from the deployed datastore and import it into the local version or to point a local instance of webapp2 to the deployed datastore for read-only transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Here i found a very good way to take dump of data and populate it , in your local database.

http://gbayer.com/big-data/app-engine-datastore-how-to-efficiently-export-your-data/

You have to take the dump , download it , and then read the entities and save them in your local database